# Difference between RunningAverageRssiFilter, ArmaRssiFilter, Kalman filter in Altbeacon SDK

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

I understand that we can have different implementations for RssiFilter using setRssiFilterImplClass in Altbeacon SDK.  I tried out all above filters (RunningAverageRssiFilter, ArmaRssiFilter, Kalman filter) and i found that there is not much difference in distances which i got. So what is the exact difference and what is the use case where in i have to select one of these filters.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Beacon Library allows different ways to filter the noise out of Bluetooth LE beacon signal strength measurements so that distance estimates are as accurate as possible.

For most users it doesn't matter which of these mechanisms you use to filter RSSI, as you have seen, they all work similarly.  Variations between filters matter mostly for moving beacons.  Each filter will introduce "lag" in the distance estimate when the beacon is moving.

A quick summary:

**RunningAverageRssiFilter** (Default): Takes the mean value of the last 20 seconds worth of RSSI measurements for a single beacon.  For moving beacons, this means that the distance estimate will tell you where the beacon was (on average) over the last 20 seconds, which for beacons moving in a straight line be where it was 10 seconds ago.  The default 20 second averaging interval is configurable.  This is the default because it is similar to the way Apple CoreLocation works, so it is useful for cross-platform compatibility.

**ArmaRssiFilter**: The Autoregressive Moving Average algorithm statistically weights the more recent samples more heavily that the older samples, leading to less lag in the distance estimates. But its behavior can be a bit indeterminate and is subject to more varying performance in different radio conditions.

**KalmanFilter**:  There is no implementation included in the library, although there is a [feature request](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/502) for one.  In theory, a Kalman Filter uses a statistical predictive model to try to discern the difference between noise and signal, and filter out the noise.  There are many variants of Kalman Filters, and different variants may be better or worse at reducing noise in specific conditions.